# How to redirect user from magento store to another website , like to facebook or twitter?

Tags: magento2.1.5

I have tried to write as follows

```
<a href='www.facebook.com'>facebook</a>
```

in my template file located at:

> /app/code/Your/Store/view/frontend/templates/todays/deal.phtml

But it is redirected to

> http://192.168.0.147/yourStore/your-store/todays/www.facebook.com/
>   So it takes me no where. 
>   In above redirected link your-store is frontname of my module in which my template resides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write as below way,

```
<a href='https://www.facebook.com'>facebook</a>
```

You have missing **`https://`** before your url.

**When you give any third party website url dont forgot to keep https:// or http:// in prefix of site url.**

Comment: You can close this question after accept as answer so other community user have useful